# Увеличение размера приложения после установки

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Занимаюсь написанием игр под андроид в юнити и в одной из игр в разделе  "о приложении" заметил значительное увеличение размера данных. Чем может быть вызвано такое разрастание данных? В других моих играх такого не наблюдается. Проверял папку приложения Android/Data/Com.... там занято всего 2 мб.
Спасибо!
[image: скриншот]

Comment: После установки APK сохраняется как есть + создаётся оптимизированная версия байт-кода + распаковываются нативные библиотеки. Возможно ещё что-то я забыл.

Comment: Да, и "данные" - это не на карте, а в памяти приложений: `/data/data/your.app.id/*`. Увидеть эти файлы можно только с рут или через [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) в студии. Проверьте что там -  в юнит-игрушках может быть немаленький кэш шейдеров, может ещё какие ресурсы распакованы/закешированы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Получил рут, нашел путь /data/data/your.app.id/files
в нём все эти мегабайты и скрылись и похоже, что это кэш рекламы юнити. Буду пытаться разобраться с кэшированием рекламы Unity ADS